# Add CSS dynamically into a checkboxlist in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

Hope you all doing fine. I am here with a problem regarding dynamically applying css into a checkboxlist.
Below are the information that i want to share with you.

**HTML Code:**

```
    <label class="checkbox-inline">   
       <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstFSOptions" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
       </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </label>
```

**C# Code:**

```
        chklstFSOptions.DataSource = dt;
        chklstFSOptions.DataTextField = "FitnessOption";
        chklstFSOptions.DataValueField = "FitnessOption";
        chklstFSOptions.DataBind();
        foreach (ListItem item in chklstFSOptions.Items)
        {
            //item.Attributes.Add("class", "badge");
            item.Text = "<span class=\"badge\">" + item.Value + "</span>";
            //chklstFSOptions.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

**HTML Output i am getting:**

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <table id="MainPlaceHolder_chklstFSOptions">
    <tr>
      <td>
          <input id="MainPlaceHolder_chklstFSOptions_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainPlaceHolder$chklstFSOptions$0" value="Gym" />
           <label for="MainPlaceHolder_chklstFSOptions_0">
             <span class="badge">Gym</span>
            </label>
           <input id="MainPlaceHolder_chklstFSOptions_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainPlaceHolder$chklstFSOptions$1" value="Yoga" />
            <label for="MainPlaceHolder_chklstFSOptions_1">
               <span class="badge">Yoga</span>
            </label>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </label>
```

**My Desired Output:**

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
 <input type="checkbox" value="" /><span class="badge">Option 2</span></label>
 <label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" value="" /><span class="badge">Option 3</span></label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" value="" /><span class="badge">Option 4</span></label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" value="" /><span class="badge">Option 5</span></label>
```

How to get my desired output?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the world of WebForms where you have next to zero control over the generated HTML output. I generally avoid most integrated webforms controls. You could approach this with a repeater where you define the needed HTML and bind your data to it. However then you might have problems with dynamically created controls if you never worked with them. I don't know what are your goals, it gets "tricky" if you are new to work with dynamic controls and reading or writing data to them.

Comment: For you information my goal is in this link https://jsfiddle.net/v523utfo/